# Accurate and reliable english or Hindi translation for Manusmriti

Tags: manu-smriti

Can someone point to me translation fro manusmriti which is of 400-500 pages maximum ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahamahopadhyaya Ganganath Jha's translation of the Manu Smriti and the commentary of Medatithi is highly respected. If you only look at the verse translation, it will probably be within 300 pages. With the commentary it will be much longer. You can read it online here.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi